# Simulating Mouse movement and dragging in a UWP application with Appium?

Tags: windows, selenium, uwp, appium

I am trying to write some highly customized UI testing code for windows UWP apps.  I am using Appium and so far I am able to simulate a click with this code just fine:

```
var item = _session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("my_page") as WindowsElement;
item.Click();
```

The `WindowsElement` does not appear to expose a way to click and drag from point to point.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example for drag and drop scenario using mouse at the WinAppDriver GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/8bb91f06ef9cbc798c88099a586c15d74fd17870/Tests/WebDriverAPI/Mouse.cs#L117). The key trick is you are not directly interacting with the element itself, but use the mouse and work with its coordinates to perform the dragging operation.

The test method looks as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MouseDownMoveUp()
{
    const int offset = 100;
    WindowsElement appNameTitle = session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("AppNameTitle");
    Assert.IsNotNull(appNameTitle);

    // Save application window original position
    Point originalPosition = session.Manage().Window.Position;
    Assert.IsNotNull(originalPosition);

    // Send mouse down, move, and up actions combination to perform a drag and drop 
    // action on the app title bar. These actions reposition Calculator window.
    session.Mouse.MouseMove(appNameTitle.Coordinates);
    session.Mouse.MouseDown(null); // Pass null as this command omit the given parameter
    session.Mouse.MouseMove(appNameTitle.Coordinates, offset, offset);
    session.Mouse.MouseUp(null); // Pass null as this command omit the given parameter
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

    // Verify that application window is now re-positioned from the original location
    Assert.AreNotEqual(originalPosition, session.Manage().Window.Position);
    Assert.IsTrue(originalPosition.Y < session.Manage().Window.Position.Y);

    // Restore application window original position
    session.Manage().Window.Position = originalPosition;
    Assert.AreEqual(originalPosition, session.Manage().Window.Position);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did not know about the explicit mouse control on the session.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it this way:

```
        var item = _session.FindElementByAccessibilityId(id) as WindowsElement;
        var actions = new Actions(_session);
        actions.MoveToElement(item)
            .ClickAndHold()
            .MoveByOffset(50,50)
            .Release()
            .Perform();
```